# AWS windows VM remote desktop connection fails

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**TL;DR** Despite following the AWS 10-minute tutorial steps to the "t", my RDP connection has failed...

Tutorial steps/setup: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/launch-windows-vm/

After step #6 (part a/b) I get this response/error message from the "Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection" client/app:

```
Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

 (1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
 (2) The remote computer is turned off
 (3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that the remote access is enabled.
```

I followed the steps exactly laid out in the tutorial -- I've got no clue as to what I'm doing wrong...Here's some other notes that might help:

- I waited for 5 minutes prior to RDP connecting (to make sure the VM booted up, I'm connecting to Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Base)
- I'm testing a free account on AWS to confirm the connection and working environment first before becoming a paid AWS customer
- My password de-crypted fine
- I wasn't prompted for a username/password during the RDP attempt
- I'm able to ping the public server IP address: (ec2-52-33-201-130.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com) or (52.33.201.130)
- I've dug around in plenty of places online to figure out what I can do to solve this problem -- I haven't found any solution so far
- I tried RDPing with default local firewall settings on and also tried it off, it made no difference
- I'm intentionally not sharing all connection details in this request/comment -- I can make that available via other communications if necessary

My computer settings are as follows:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- RAM: 32 GBs
- Processor: Intel Core i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz
- Local Firewall Settings (tried RDPing with it "On" and "Off" -- made no difference)

***Please help in anyway possible!!***  Let me know if I'm missing any details. Thanks again.

Comment: Is port 3389 (RDP) open on your AWS instance security group?

Comment: Yes, the security group info/settings are as follows....(1) Type: RDP (2) Protocol: TCP (3) Port Range: 3389 (4) Source: 0.0.0.0/0.....The name of the default launch Group Name is **launch-wizard-1**

Comment: I just tried doing rdp to your machine using the public ip (52.33.201.130) and it worked - of course I don't know the password for administrator so I got an error, but it did initiate the remote connection and verified the password. So if you can't connect it might be something from your local network blocking port 3389

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so file this under "really strange setup" on my router...Liviu Costea helped me alot when you told me you were able to "reach" the box from a different network location-- thank you very much!  Hope this helps some folks in the future with a "wonky" network setup.

- I went to my **router settings (192.168.1.1)** logged in as an admin
- I have a Verizon FiOS that's connected to my Netgear and other routers/hubs
- I went to **Firewall Settings** -- everything looked good there
- I went to **Access Control** (a sub menu item within Firewall settings) and noticed some *insane* looking rules there that were **Blocking these ports/connections...**

  - [WindowsRDP] - TCP Any -> 3389 UDP Any -> 3389
  - [WindowsRDPt3390] - TCP 3390 -> 3390 WindowsRDPu3390 - UDP 3390 -> 3390
- After disabling those rules, I was able to RDP easily into the AWS boxes
- Something odd to note as well -- when I'm VPNing into my companies network, these RDP rules are completely side-stepped (aka ignored) and I'm able to remote into any of my company boxes --- I had no idea that my local RDP connections were being blocked by my router rules.

Clearly I had no clue these rules were setup on my box (it could have been a while back when I was messing around with my RaspberryPi or something like that on my network) -- pretty crazy.  Hope this helps out anyone else that might run into RDP woes.